# Convert simple array to numeric key and value

Tags: arrays, json, indexing, jq

I'm really struggling with this simple task. I'm trying to convert this:

```
[
    "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/masters.a.eu.somewhere.com",
    "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/masters.b.eu.somewhere.com",
    "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/masters.c.eu.somewhere.com"
]
```

To something like this:

```
{
    "0": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/masters.a.eu.somewhere.com",
    "1": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/masters.b.eu.somewhere.com",
    "2": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/masters.c.eu.somewhere.com"
}
```

Using just JQ. I've tried using 'to_entries' but I'm not getting the desired output. Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Where are `a`, `b` and `c` coming from? Just `a` for the first element, `b` for the second etc., or extracted from the URL somehow?

Comment: Just a for the first, b for the second, c for the third. I've ammended my example with numbered elements as that was as close as I could get with to_entries. Just not the desired format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Admittedly this is not obvious, but a very short solution is:

```
with_entries(.key |= tostring)
```

A more pedestrian but still perfectly respectable solution would be:

```
. as $in
| reduce range(0;length) as $i ({}; . + {($i|tostring): $in[$i]})
```

Comment: A maybe slightly more scrutable version (that doesn't depend on the "arrays have number keys, objects have string keys" magic) would be `to_entries | map({ (.key | tostring): .value }) | add`

Comment: Very much appreciated. As you say not obvious but logical now I see it. Upvoted the additional suggestion from hobbs as I can see that being more useful to me down the line with regards additional transformations.